# Accessing super class function using subclass object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an object of a subclass extending its superclass. There is an overridden method in subclass which can be called using the object. 
Is that possible to call the superclass's function using the subclass object?

```
package supercall;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass obj = new SubClass();
        obj.go();   //is there anything like, obj.super.go()?
    }

}

class SomeClass {
    SomeClass() {

    }
    public void go() {
        System.out.println("Someclass go");
    }
}

class SubClass extends SomeClass {
    SubClass() {

    }
    @Override
    public void go() {
        System.out.println("Subclass go");
    }
}
```

Consider the code above.

Here it prints

> Subclass go

. Instead I have to print

> Superclass go

.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it's not possible, and if you think you need it, rethink your design. The whole point of overriding a method is to replace its functionality. If a different class knows that much about that class's internal workings, you're completely killing encapsulation.

Comment: but then whats the point of super keyword, its one and the same, this is just syntactically not possible, I cannot find any logic behind it.

Comment: The point of the super keyword is that it allows you to access the overridden functionality *in the class that overrides it*. That absolutely makes sense for things like decorators. And it's a very different matter than this question which is about a *different* class accessing superclass functionality through a subclass object. Which makes absolutely no sense, it's basically the third class saying "I don't care what the subclass implementor intended, I want to do it differently!"

Answer (score 3):

*Here it prints 
Subclass go
. Instead I have to print 
Superclass go*

Alright, then do not override go method @ subclass, it will call superclass implementation.

If you want to run super implementation, and have some other additional code @ subclass, you call super.go(); and then run some other statements.

It's ok, as you are reusing already written code, you shouldn't copy-paste code from superclass and put it into subs as it's code duplication. But if your goal is to change behaviour completely, then don't call super

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
System.out.println("Subclass go");
```

Write

```
super.go();
```

(Or, you know, just don't implement that method ...).

Comment: Yeah. But sometimes I would use subclass's method too. Isn't it possible to call the superclass's method in someother way? something like obj.super.go()??? Of course, this is a wrong construct. I meant something similar??

Comment: @bdhar: Yeah, you can just call `super`. But you need to make that call from *in* the class. It can't be done externally.

Comment: @silky.. Could you please provide a example for what u mentioned in above thread-- "you need to make that call from in the class. It can't be done externally"

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to achieve this? No, there isn't.

At runtime the JVM will pick the methods to call based on the instance type (that's polymorphism for you), not based on the type it is declared with.

Your instance is a subclass instance, so the go() method in the subclass will be called.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make the subclass call teh super classes implementation. But I'm assuming thats not what you want?

```
class SubClass extends SomeClass {    
SubClass() {}    
    @Override    
    public void go() {    
        super.go
    }
}
```

Comment: @Steve.. Calling superclass function using super keyword is indeed the correct way. What I wanted to know was if there is any other way to invoke the superclass go() method using "obj" as the reference??