# how to get the implementation of a superclass from a subclass using upcasting or by other methods?

Tags: java, downcast, upcasting

i just wanted to know how to get the implementation of a superclass using a subclass, for example.

```
class Animal {
    void poo() {
        System.out.println("general poo");
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal{
    void poo() {
        System.out.println("horse poo");
    }
}

Animal animal1 = new Horse(); 
// using this I get the implementation of the Horse class's methods
animal1.poo(); //should return horse poo
```

tried to upcast it to get the super class implementation but to no avail

```
((Animal)animal1).poo() // still returns the horse class's implementation of the method
```

How do I get the superclass implementation using the animal1 object?

Comment: This would be possible if it's C#.

Comment: This is not possible. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432249/accessing-super-class-function-using-subclass-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, you should not override a superclass method unless the new method is intended to be a total replacement for all external calls to the method.

Within the sublcass implementation, you can use e.g. super.toString() to reference the immediate superclass method.

Comment: That. `Horse.poo` should be fully compliant with the contract/specification of `Animal.poo`; if it is not true you have a trouble with your design.

Comment: @Patricia. Thanks for the answer. I guess the best way to do this is to created a method that would do the super.method(). :D

Comment: You need to decide which is the normal way of doing poo in your new subclass. That should override the superclass method. You can either add a new method to do the new thing, or add a new method to do the superclass version. However, I suggest carefully reviewing your design - hitting this problem is often a symptom of confusion about what methods are meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

Beside it is not possible, it does not make sense, try to redsign your class.

Comment: yeah, i agree to that. and so are the test questions that i encounter when i apply for jobs.