# How to select an overrided method?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have this code:

```
    class Amphibian {
      public void moveInWater(){
      System.out.println("Moving in water");
    }
}
    public class Frog extends Amphibian {
      public void moveInWater() {
      System.out.println("... from the Land");
 }
      public static void main (String[] args) {
      Frog wood = new Frog();
      wood.moveInWater();
    }
}
```

I know the method overrided will get the output:
"...from the Land" and if I put super.moveInWater(); in the base class the method will get "Moving in water". 
There is a way to choice the called of the method from base or derivate at my pleasure? In substance, to maintain both the outputs and to select one or another of two.

Grazie

Comment: change your method name to `moveInWater()`

Comment: @DimaSan: Yes, sorry :)

Comment: Also, you're missing a `}` at the end of function `moveInWater()` of `Frog` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Polymorphism How to call to super class method for subclass object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907424/java-polymorphism-how-to-call-to-super-class-method-for-subclass-object)

Comment: @CarlosRivero: because I made the code by smartphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to define a new method...

```
public void moveAsAmphibian(){

    super.moveInWater();
}
```