# Calling a superclass method from a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, bank

I'm modelling a bank account with a superclass `Account` and a subclass `SavingsAccount` that can't be overdrawn. The `makeWithdrawal()` method, when called from the main class, should check if the withdrawal is greater than the balance and prompt for input, then edit the balance.

How can I call the `makeWithdrawal()` method from `Account` and override it in `SavingsAccount` using the super keyword? My compiler is giving me "error: incompatible types: missing return value.

Method in `Account`:

```
double makeWithdrawal(double withdrawal)    {
    return balance -= withdrawal;
}
```

(Pretty simple.) This method was initially abstract, but it was causing errors.

Method in `SavingsAccount`:

```
    public double makeWithdrawal(double withdrawal) {
        double tempbalance = getBalance();
        if (withdrawal > getBalance())  {
            withdrawal = Input.getDouble("Your withdrawal cannot be larger than your balance. Enter a withdrawal <= "+getBalance());
            return;
        }
        else    {
            return super.makeWithdrawal(withdrawal);
            }
    }
```

Comment: `super.makeWithdrawal()`

Comment: I had super.makeWithdrawal() in SavingsAccount in else().

Comment: and what happens when you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Polymorphism How to call to super class method for subclass object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907424/java-polymorphism-how-to-call-to-super-class-method-for-subclass-object)

Comment: OP, you need to indicate *where* the error occurs. The answer is much simpler than you make it sound.

Comment: I get the error of missing return value. Or, it says that I can't override the superclass method.

Comment: Is your superclass `final`?

Comment: (Yeah sorry I'm a noob programmer) The error is at the end of the if statement in SavingsAccount

Comment: No, it's a public abstract class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

> return;

You should replace it by

> return withdrawal;

```
    public double makeWithdrawal(double withdrawal) {
    double tempbalance = getBalance();
    if (withdrawal > getBalance())  {
        withdrawal = Input.getDouble("Your withdrawal cannot be larger than your balance. Enter a withdrawal <= "+getBalance());
        return withdrawal;
    }
    else    {
        return super.makeWithdrawal(withdrawal);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with your call to `super.makeWithdrawl()`, which is correct. It is with the empty `return` statement in the `if` clause above it. Your logic to get the update the withdrawal amount is sensible, but you need to return the new balance when you do that. I would recommend just moving the call to `super.makeWithdrawl()` outside the conditonal:

```
if(withdrawal > getBalance())  {
    withdrawal = Input.getDouble("Your withdrawal cannot be larger than your balance. Enter a withdrawal <= "+getBalance());
}
return super.makeWithdrawal(withdrawal);
```

This will use the updated withdrawal amount if the original one was too large.

Answer (score 0):

in the if

```
if (withdrawal > getBalance())  {
            withdrawal = Input.getDouble("Your withdrawal cannot be larger than your balance. Enter a withdrawal <= "+getBalance());
            return;
        }
```

you need to return double value rather than simple returning.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly:

Account is the base class and SavingsAccount the subclass?

then: `super.makeWithdrawal(withdrawal);`

also make sure you inherit when defining the class:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{...}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.