# How to call the superclass implementation of an overridden method from inside the superclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass, subclassing, overriding

Suppose I have two classes `SuperClass` and `SubClass` which extends `SuperClass`, such as below:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    private Object field1;

    protected SuperClass(Object obj) {
        setField1(obj);
    }

    public void setField1(Object obj) {
        // perform some check on obj and
        // then set field1 such that field1==obj
    }
}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public SubClass(Object obj) {
        super(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void setField1(Object obj) {
        super.setField1(obj);
        // do some work that is necessary only when
        // field1 is set through SubClass.setField1()
    }
}
```

What I need is, when I create an object of `SubClass`, I need method `SuperClass.setField1()` to be called from inside `SuperClass` constructor, not `SubClass.setField1()`. But with the above code, method `SubClass.setField1()` is called which causes a `NullPointerException` to be thrown, since the work done in `SubClass.setField1()` is performed on a field that's yet null.

Is there any way to explicitly call `SuperClass.setField1()‍‍‍` from inside `SuperClass` constructor?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595512/java-calling-a-super-method-which-calls-an-overridden-method#4595762

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Polymorphism How to call to super class method for subclass object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907424/java-polymorphism-how-to-call-to-super-class-method-for-subclass-object)

Comment: Why does it cause ```NullPointerException``` to be thrown?

Comment: @zhh Because the additional work in overridden method is performed on fields that are declared in `SubClass` and are not instantiated yet, since the `super` command must be called first of all, in `SubClass` constructor.

Comment: From which line NullPointerException is coming? Can you please paste the whole code how you are invoking the constructor and which parameters you are passing to it?

Comment: I think we can find a solution as requested, but actually your problem arises from calling a polymorphous method from a constructor. This is discouraged in Java (because such strange effects can occur). Use e.g. a static factory to work around this - and you will not have to solve this problem. Do you need help for the static factory?

Comment: [Calling overrideable methods from inside a constructor is well-known to be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/3788176). Just don't do it.

Comment: @CoronA I'm familiar with static factories. But I'm not sure if this can be applied to my example. In my actual program, the SuperClass corresponds to an abstract class called `MilitaryUnit` which has a field `graphic` (corresponding to `field1`). And a subclass called `MovableUnit` which introduces the additional field `animation` that applies to `graphic` to move it. In class `MovableUnit` when `super()` is called,  there's no animation yet, but it calls method `setGraphic()`. Every time a new `graphic` is set, it must be introduced to `animation` in method `MovableUnit.setGraphic()`.

Comment: @CoronA I'm not sure if I could explain the situation clearly.

Comment: It would be best if you add some code the reproduces the problem. I understand why a static factory is not applicable, but yet I do not understand why you call `setField` in your constructor. Just copy and paste the contents of `setField`, not every copy and paste is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move said method body to a private method and let the default method (the one which may be overridden by the subclass) delegate to the former. See this example

```
public abstract class SuperClass {

    private Object field1;

    protected SuperClass(Object obj){
        // call the safe implementation
        setField1Safe(obj);
    }


    public void setField1(Object obj){
        // just delegates
        setField1Safe(obj);
    }

    private void setField1Safe(Object obj){
        // perform some check on obj and
        // then set field1 such that field1==obj
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
     public SubClass(Object obj){
         super(obj);
     }

     @Override
     public void setField1(Object obj){
         super.setField1(obj);
         // do some work that is necessary only when
         // field1 is set through SubClass.setField1()
     }
}
```

That way the sub class can still override `setField1` but if you really depend on the implementation then you can call the private `setField1Safe` method.

Comment: if he is gonna make the method private then there will not be any method overriding .he is trying override the methods

Comment: I think Lino should rewrite his example and adjust it to the given one. I supect that the method `doStuff` is meant to be inherited while `doStuffButPrivate` is called from the constructor.

Comment: @CoronA that's what I intended to tell with this, I've updated to reflect the changes OP should made in his code